# I found that I'm trying to write an web app behaves exactly like the django admin. What should I do?

Tags: python, django

This may seem quite a weird question but I'm quite confused right now and don't know what to do.

I'm working on an intranet web app using django. Soon I found that almost all features I need are done in django-admin, like adding and editing entries, view and filter items in a list view and so on. The missing parts can be done with some other additional views.

Should I just wrap up the admin app or should I re-implement the admin by myself? Or I should use something other than django like GWT or extJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your motivation.  If this is an exercise in sharpening yourself then I suggest reinventing it. Mainly because you learn so much in the process. If the main goal is just to have the functionality then use the django-admin and bolt on whatever you need that it lacks.